# Exception has occurred: TypeError cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object

Tags: python, python-3.x

i was working on a python bot meant to automatically switch the mouse position for a clicker game and i keep randomly getting this error. i thought giving it a value every time it runs the while command would fix it but it didn't show any improvements. from what i saw using the program if it scans and doesn't find any of the 2 images it is trying to locate.

Error message:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
  File "C:\Users\gpetr\Desktop\New folder (3)\program.py", line 21, in <module>
    px, py = eyeloc
```

Code is as shown below:

```
from pyautogui import *
import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard
import random
import win32api, win32con

def click(x,y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,0,0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,0,0)

eyeloc = 997, 456

while keyboard.is_pressed('q') == False:
    eyeloc = 997, 456
    if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('pink.png', region=(576, 160, 842, 592), confidence=0.8)  != None:
        eyeloc = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('pink.png', region=(576, 160, 842, 592), confidence=0.8)
        print("pink")
        px, py = eyeloc  
        pyautogui.moveTo(px, py+130, 0.2)
        time.sleep(0.4)
    elif pyautogui.locateOnScreen('gold.png', region=(576, 160, 842, 593), confidence=0.8)  != None:
        eyeloc = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('gold.png', region=(576, 160, 842, 592), confidence=0.8)
        print("gold")
        gx, gy = eyeloc
        pyautogui.moveTo(gx, gy+130, 0.2)
        time.sleep(0.4)
```

Comment: Can you add the full error message? In which line does the error occur?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Check out the [tour]. For debugging help, please provide a [mre] including the error. It will help us and you better understand the problem.

Comment: My best guess is that `locateCenterOnScreen` is returning `None`, so when you try to unpack it, the error is thrown

Comment: Are you checking for `ImageNotFoundException` after you locateCenterOnScreen?

Comment: Also look at the region parameters you are passing in `locateOnScreen` vs. `locateCenterOnScreen`. The values are `region=(576, 160, 842, 592)` vs `region=(576, 160, 842, 593)`. 592 vs 593

Answer (score 0):

I added a copy of eyeloc called eyelocc that is given a value outside of the while command. Inside the first if i added

```
if eyeloc == None:
    eyeloc = eyelocc
```

At the end of the first if eyelocc takes the value of eyeloc so that the next time eyeloc equals to none it will receive it's last usable value.
I ran the program for about 10 minutes without experiencing any issues.
The final draft of the code looks like this:

```
from pyautogui import *
import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard
import random
import win32api, win32con

eyelocc = 997, 456

while keyboard.is_pressed('q') == False:
    if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('pink.png', region=(576, 160, 842, 592), confidence=0.8)  != None:
        eyeloc = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('pink.png', region=(576, 160, 842, 592), confidence=0.8)
        if eyeloc == None:
            eyeloc = eyelocc
        px, py = eyeloc
        pyautogui.moveTo(px, py+130, 0.2)
        time.sleep(0.4)
        eyelocc = eyeloc
    elif pyautogui.locateOnScreen('gold.png', region=(576, 160, 842, 593), confidence=0.8)  != None:
        eyeloc = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('gold.png', region=(576, 160, 842, 592), confidence=0.8)
        if eyeloc == None:
            eyeloc = eyelocc
        gx, gy = eyeloc
        pyautogui.moveTo(gx, gy+130, 0.2)  
        time.sleep(0.4)    
        eyelocc = eyeloc
```